# ReplayKit square recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, replaykit

I was wondering is there any way to force replaykit to record only a part of the screen in square mode? The current API seems to record the whole screen!

Comment: The guy at wwdc said something about specifying another UIWindow for a similar purpose. Not sure if that UIWindow can be square or if it has to be full screen but I guess the purpose is to only record certain parts.

Answer (score 3):

ReplayKit records everything on the screen exempt system prompts and dialogs.

You can however overlay another UIWindow on top of your main one and apply a mask to an empty UIView to hide parts of the screen and force a square recording.

The frame ratio of the final recording will still be equal to the screen though.

```
    _overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds]; //Full sized window
    _overlayWindow.backgroundColor =  [UIColor clearColor];
    _overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    _overlayWindow.hidden = NO;

UIView *maskedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_overlayWindow.bounds];

    // Create a mask layer 
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    CGRect maskRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

    // Create a path with the rectangle in it.
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(maskRect, NULL);

    maskLayer.path = path;
    // Set the mask of the view.
    maskedView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

[_overlayWindow addSubview:maskedView];
```

Comment: Thanks I will look into it

Comment: can u guide me on this?

Comment: I have tried above ur code. But, recordings done with full screen. I can't record a particular CGRect

Comment: @ahbou kindly guide me on this

Comment: @McDonal_11 ReplayKit doesn't support recording a particular frame. But you can overlay you mainWindow with a mask like the code above

Comment: I need to crop particular frame in video file like image crop . Is it possible ?

Comment: Suppose, If am having 5 mins video and I am trying to play in AVPlayer, with frame 375 * 400, then now I need to crop particular frame, 200 * 200 either in top, left or center, Is it possible? I don't want compress video size to be 200*200

Comment: @ahbou Do u having any idea? Can guide me pls?

Comment: ReplayKit doesn't support that unfortunately. You'll have to crop after the recording is done.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment ReplayKit framework does not provide customisation of Screen Recording in terms of Screen size. So you have to record whole screen of GamePlay.

Comment: Do you know any alternative way to record an UIView ?

Comment: I don't know any other way for View Recording.